# Are TPM PCRs volatile, non-volatile, or both?

Tags: tpm, trusted-computing, volatility

Do PCRs (Platform Configuration Registers) on TPMs (Trusted Platform Modules) retain their data on reboot?

I'm trying to find out if all (or some) of the PCRs on a TPM are volatile (will loose their memory on power loss) or nonvolatile (will retain their memory on power loss).

Are all PCRs volatile or nonvolatile? Does it depend on the implementation? How can you find out which PCRs are volatile and which are nonvolatile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PCR's used for platform measurements in TPM are volatile.

If you are looking for non-volatile memory with similar functionality to PCR's check for NV storage in TPM. They can be configured to work like PCR's using policies.